# Javascript the good parts:can't understand method array.push

Tags: javascript

I'm reading Douglas Crockford's Javascript the good parts,but I can't understand the implemention of *Array.push* in the chapter 8 Methods,as follows:

```js
Function.prototype.method = function(name,func){
    if(!this.prototype[name]){
        this.prototype[name] = func;
    }
};

Array.method('mypush',function(){
    this.splice.apply(this,[this.length,0].concat(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)));

    return this.length;
});

var arr = [1,2,3];
arr.mypush(2,3);
console.log(arr);
```

I can't understand this statement:

```js
this.splice.apply(this,[this.length,0].concat(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do that from the inside out:

1. `Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)` --- converts `arguments` array-like object into a real array
2. `[this.length,0].concat(#1)` --- concatenates the hardcoded `[this.length,0]` array with the array from #1
3. `this.splice.apply(this, #2)` --- applies the `this.splice` function to `this` object with arguments from #2

Finally it will look like: `this.splice(this.length, 0, arg1, arg2, arg3)` which means: at the index equal to `this.length` (see "in the very end) replace `0` elements (see - don't remove anything) with the given arguments.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

`apply` takes a function and calls it on the supplied `this` object and parameters taken from an array.

```
this.splice.apply(this,[this.length,0].concat(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)));
```

So, what we have here is:

```
this.splice        // a reference to the function "splice" that an Array has

this.splice.apply  // invoke this function 

this.splice.apply(this   // invoke it on "this" 

this.splice.apply(this,[     // with an array of parameters

    [this.length,0]   // the first two parameters are "the length", and a "0"

    // calling splice this way means replacing the 0 elements 
    // after the end of the array with the following new elements
    // => i.e. pushing the new elements 

    ].concat     // but we add some more parameters

    Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)    
        // namely the arguments passed into this function
```

That last step is necessary because `arguments` is not a real array, so it does not work with concat. `slice` makes a copy of it (into a real array).

Summing it all up with an example.

If you called `[1,2,3].mypush(2,3)` it translates into `[1,2,3].splice(3, 0, 2, 3)`;